# video resolution of iMovie app export in iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, imovie, resolution, video

What are the export resolutions of a video shot on iPhone 4S and exported from iMovie app (after editing)? Also, is there a way I can export original resolution, (1080p) video to youtube from within the iPhone app of iMovie.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the new Garageband (iOS 5.1) supports 1080p video.

Comment: Means I have to buy another app and it cannot be done through iMovie itself?

Comment: No. You should be able to export 1080p directly from iMovie.